# Sling servlet invalid recursion selector with json extension

Tags: aem, sling

I am registering a Sling Servlet using

```
@Component(service=Servlet.class,
           property={
                   Constants.SERVICE_DESCRIPTION + "=Simple Demo Servlet",
                   "sling.servlet.methods=" + HttpConstants.METHOD_GET,
                   "sling.servlet.resourceTypes="+ "myapp/components/structure/page",
                   "sling.servlet.extensions=" + "json",
                   "sling.servlet.selectors=" + "myselector"
 })
```

But when calling URL `<host:port>/content/myapp/en.myselector.js` I get error

```
Invalid recursion selector value 'myselector'
Cannot serve request to /content/myapp/en.myselector.json in 
org.apache.sling.servlets.get.DefaultGetServlet
```

If we remove `"sling.servlet.extensions=" + "json",` from annotation, we are able to hit the servlet using `<host:port>/content/myapp/en.myselector.js`  or `<host:port>/content/myapp/en.myselector.html`  but not `<host:port>/content/myapp/en.myselector.json`

Any additional configurations required? or its conflicting with `DefaultGetServlet`? We were trying to expose JSON out of resource using servlet and JSON extension semantically making sense.

Comment: Did you try using `<host:port>/content/myapp/en/_jcr_content.myselector.json`. Since you are registering the servlet against the resource, the resource type for the page would in the `jcr:content` node and not on the page node itself.

Comment: Thanks @rakhi4110, it works with `jcr:content`. I think when both selector and extension is there path till `jcr:content` is required, else if only selector is there it works without `jcr:content` for `.js` of `.html`. You can post answer, I can accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you've registered the servlet against the resource instead of a path, the resource is actually the `jcr:content` node of the page, rather than the page node itself.

Hence, the servlet should work when accessed with the `jcr:content` in the URL as shown below

`<host:port>/content/myapp/en/_jcr_content.myselector.json`